# Generic function where array parameter constructs generic type

Tags: typescript

I have a generic function which takes a array as parameter and I would like to construct the generic type that has been passed in by the array. The function is working fine but I would like too add a type to check if the array keys would make up the generic type if not it should throw out a Typescript error.

Interfaces

```
interface OutputType {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  age: number;
}

interface ArrayType {
  key: string;
  value: any;
}
```

Generic function

```
function TestType<T>(array: ArrayType[]): T {
  let newObj = {} as T;

  array.forEach((arrayItem) => {
    newObj[arrayItem.key as keyof T] = arrayItem.value;
  });

  return newObj;
}
```

This should result in a TS **ERROR **because its missing 'id' property

```
const array = [ 
  {
    key: "name",
    value: "TestName",
  },
  {
    key: "age",
    value: 12,
  },
] as ArrayType[];
```

This should clear the TS error

```
const array = [
  {
    key: "id",
    value: "1",
  },
  {
    key: "name",
    value: "TestName",
  },
  {
    key: "age",
    value: 12,
  },
] as ArrayType[];
```

Here is the full sample code:
https://playcode.io/1019051

I am currently stuck when I tried implementing a custom type for the array parameter.

I would like to create a custom type to do the check on the array being passed in and validate is against the generic type properties

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is definitely a tricky problem. To solve this, you will have to take the generic type `T` and generate all valid array Permutations from it.

Given a type `T`

```
interface OutputType {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  age: number;
}
```

the union of valid arrays would look like this:

```
type Permutations = [{
    key: "id";
    value: string;
}, {
    key: "name";
    value: string;
}, {
    key: "age";
    value: number;
}] | [{
    key: "id";
    value: string;
}, {
    key: "age";
    value: number;
}, {
    key: "name";
    value: string;
}] | [...] | [...] | [...] | ...
```

We can derive such a union using a generic type.

```
type CreatePermutations<
  T extends Record<string, any>, 
  K extends keyof T = keyof T, 
  C extends keyof T = K
> = 
  [K] extends [never]
    ? []
    : K extends K
      ? [{ key: K, value: T[K] }, ...CreatePermutations<T, Exclude<C, K>>]
      : never
```

and use this generic type in the function definition.

```
function TestType<
  T extends Record<string, any>
>(array: CreatePermutations<T> & ArrayType[]): T {
  let newObj = {} as T;

  array.forEach((arrayItem) => {
    newObj[arrayItem.key as keyof T] = arrayItem.value;
  });

  return newObj;
}
```

This leads to a compile time error when the given input to the function does not match the calculated permutations based on the given generic type `T`.

```
// Error: Source has 2 element(s) but target requires 3.(2345)
TestType<OutputType>([ 
  {
    key: "name",
    value: "TestName",
  },
  {
    key: "age",
    value: 12,
  },
])

TestType<OutputType>([
  {
    key: "id",
    value: "1",
  },
  {
    key: "name",
    value: "TestName",
  },
  {
    key: "age",
    value: 12,
  },
])
```

The problem with this implementation is that it is combinatory explosive. Calculating a union of all possible combinations will become expensive for objects with more properties.

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgPIFcwAdMBUCeWKA3gFDLLAAmAXMgM5hSgDmA3OciHALYR2NmIdpzgt+XdDwBG0DgF9SpUJFiIUAQShQ4+AkWRkKAawj4BTVhwoA3OABt0EuCHwKlMdCARhgAexBkXAhGfQgAHlxkCAAPSBAqemQAJQgEPygqcMFWABpkF3wAPiKACjhtXToAYSgIOEgABWgeTAb-EHpIouQAMmQtHT1CCABtAF0ASjooo2R7CDAuCAB3VGkAK2QAXkN5AqTcDlFK-AA6GAyAUUQAC1Ly04BJSB5JnZ65ihBV9Y3RipDF4QHhnUz4A7IcF+GBBcY7ArPV5nOyOCDWZDySbHCh1MDoKCBH5rTbuUhgEbIWr1JotNq+AJdThRWLxRIpNIZLI5YT5QpFfKcADS0TiEASSWhsKiuylQUFFGqorZkrMMKCCKFpB6u04oyF8NZ4vZox+Nmg404FAA-MgJlbkHQRUaJcgtRQPchbaNiFCzE78qinDN9fD5PkzpHqQ0IM0oK0wO1GZF8lcYghHFQItV8kKSpbPRQ6GboA6KEoAPQV5BXbQZOgAZT8BKQyFucCSACZogs+OBSvR3tJMMhE1BxEs6gBHdDAOpJADMZ1KnYXABYAKyTUjBUIjcIYbB4EZlUbIThfP3mZAAIm4fBvuQdQYkN93YAAcrwII-OOGLw64J0DeYg-k+novnQACMnbgZiT5TEo75hAemA4GAYSngBnpAbe1C-hBDjBreUEEfB2Eerhd7fmRthEa+75fg+cH-hQl5UaBtHIJByAwSxCGTEAA)

Comment: Thanks for the answer although the custom type is working when you pass the function a raw array, if I pass an array of type `ArrayType` it results in a `Type 'ArrayType[]' is not assignable to type '[{ key: "age"; value: number; }, { key: "name"; value: string; }, { key: "id"; value: string; }] & ArrayType[]'. ts(2345)` error

Comment: Yes, that is to be expected. You have to either pass an array literal to the function or declare the arrays you are passing with `as const` and without an explicit type. Giving an array the type `ArrayType[]` strips away any information about the actual elements and length of the array

Comment: Any study material you know of to help me understand writing complex types from the above?